# Irradiance and computer graphics

Tags: graphics, rendering, real-time

In Real Time Rendering 3rd Edition,

[image]

I don't get it. Do we only measure irradiance that is perpendicular to l?

Or does the author want to emphasize that we care about irradiance with respect to the surface normal, n?

Answer (score 0):

The emission of a directional light source can be quantified by measuring power through a unit area surface perpendicular to a direction.

Irradiance perpendicular to l measures the irradiance of the light source.

Irradiance perpendicular to n measures the irradiance of the surface being illuminated.

Comment: "Irradiance perpendicular to n measures the irradiance of the surface being illuminated." - Is this an outgoing irradiance from the surface? Or is this incoming irradiance to the surface?